# How to optimize Select Query using SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sqldataadapter

I'm using SqlDataAdapter to search Datas like this :

```
tableDataAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from Table";
tableDataAdapter.fill("table");
```

Is there a method to optimize it ?
thanks.

Comment: LOL ! @HenkHolterman I mean : if I have 1000000 rows in the Table X, so my query will take several minutes to get the result !

Comment: Then getting exactly the right columns is extra important.

Comment: do [paging](https://www.google.com.tr/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=sql+paging+dataadapter+row_number&oq=sql+paging+dataadapter+row_number&gs_l=hp.3...44466.47630.4.47826.11.11.0.0.0.0.375.2436.0j6j2j3.11.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.zRmeCuTpV0I&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41018144,d.Yms&fp=20495865339e6725&biw=1920&bih=975) in your queries

Comment: Do you need every single record/column?  Specify columns and add a WHERE clause.

Comment: Ok, but if I set a TextBox to seach some columns from the Table X, and I want to get result on TextBox.ChangeTextValue !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below mentioned general rules to improve query performance.

1. Improve Indexes

   - Creating useful indexes is one of the most important ways to achieve better query performance. Useful indexes help you find data with fewer disk I/O operations and less system resource usage.
2. Choose What to Index

   - We recommend that you always create indexes on primary keys. It is frequently useful to also create indexes on foreign keys. This is because primary keys and foreign keys are frequently used to join tables. Indexes on these keys lets the optimizer consider more efficient index join algorithms. If your query joins tables by using other columns, it is frequently helpful to create indexes on those columns for the same reason.
3. Rewrite Subqueries to Use JOIN

   - Sometimes you can rewrite a subquery to use JOIN and achieve better performance. The advantage of creating a JOIN is that you can evaluate tables in a different order from that defined by the query.
4. Use Parameterized Queries

   - If your application runs a series of queries that are only different in some constants, you can improve performance by using a parameterized query. For example, to return orders by different customers, you can run the following query:

> SELECT "Customer ID" FROM Orders WHERE "Order ID" = ?

For more information check [**Query Performance Tuning**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172984.aspx)

I hope this will help to you.